# How to allow to choose the end date at least 12 hours after the start date for antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have **RangePicker** for select start date and end date.

```
<RangePicker
    showTime={{
        hideDisabledOptions: true,
        defaultValue: [moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss'), moment('11:59:59', 'HH:mm:ss')],
    }}
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
/>
```

How I can allow the user to select the end time at **least 12 hours** 
after the selected start date (also in hours and minutes)?

I found this example, but I do not quite understand how to adjust it to my version

```
const range = (start, end) => {
    const result = [];
  
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  
    return result;
  };
  
  // function for setting timepicker in rangepicker
  const disabledRangeTime = (_, type) => {
    if (type === 'end') {
      return {
        disabledHours: () => range(0, 60).splice(4, 20),
      };
    }
    return {
      disabledHours: () => range(0, 60).splice(20, 4),
    };
  };
```

Also connect this function for my **RangePicker**

```
<RangePicker
    showTime={{
        hideDisabledOptions: true,
        defaultValue: [moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss'), moment('11:59:59', 'HH:mm:ss')],
    }}
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    disabledDate={disabledDate}
    disabledTime={disabledRangeTime}
/>
```

I will be really happy if someone helps me! Thank's! :)

Comment: Maybe need change range properties? But how I can do it?

Comment: how to forbid in the final date to choose today?